# Redirect entire website to https - non-www to www except subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to setup my .htaccess to perform the following redirects for my website. (I have spent quite some time researching SO and found lots of questions related to htaccess redirect but not this specific one.)

```
 1. www.example.com
 2. http://www.example.com
 3. example.com
 4. http://example.com
 5. https://example.com


to https://www.example.com
```

However any subdomains should NOT be redirected to www or https
 i.e. `support.example.com`

Should NOT be redirected to `https://support.example.com` or `www.support.example.com`

I currently have the following redirect code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This correctly redirects

```
 1. www.example.com
 2. http://www.example.com

to https://www.example.com
```

and also prevents the subdomains from redirecting.

However

```
 3. example.com
 4. http://example.com
 5. https://example.com
```

are redirected to

```
 https://example.com
```

P.S. I have put the links inside code-blocks because I dont have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and see how it works for you and let me know.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is incredible. Works great. Thanks for the lightning quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
              # BEGIN WordPress
              <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteBase //
              RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
              </IfModule>

              Redirect 301 / http://sample1.com
              # END WordPress
```

for example..

A:sample.com
B:sample1.com

if you want to redirect sample.com to sample1.com then u should include sample1.com next to redirect 301.

Comment: -Thanks very much for your reponse. I dont use Wordpress so I couldnt really test your solution.