# 301 redirect from one directory to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the sitewide redirect solution provided by @Panama Jack 
      [Redirect entire website to https - non-www to www except subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463693/redirect-entire-website-to-https-non-www-to-www-except-subdomains)

In addition, I also need a 301 re-direct from one directory to another i.e.

Redirect FROM

```
 1. www.example.com/directory1/?q1=1234&page=1
 2. http://www.example.com/directory1/?q1=1234&page=1
 3. example.com/directory1/?q1=1234&page=1
 4. http://example.com/directory1/?q1=1234&page=1
 5. https://example.com/directory1/?q1=1234&page=1
```

To

```
 https://www.example.com/directory2/?q1=1234&page=1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this new rule below your earlier 301 `http->https` rule:

```
RewriteRule ^directory1(/.*)?$ /directory2$1 [NC,L,NE,R=301]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be automatically carried over to target URL.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava! I will try your response tonight and will accept this answer once I validate it. Will report back if I see issues. Really appreciate the super quick response!

Comment: Sure, take your time and leave a comment here if it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! I am accepting your anwer. I also need to have a 301 redirect for the following 

REDIRECT FROM
1) www.example.com/directory1/dirA/
2) www.example.com/directory1/dirB/
REDIRECT TO
1) www.example.com/directory2/new-path-dirA/
2) www.example.com/directory2/new-path-dirB/
Would you please suggest the rewrite rule for this? Thanks again!

Comment: For `/directory1/dirA/ => /directory1/dirB/` you can have this rule: `RewriteRule ^directory1/dirA(/.*)?$ /directory1/dirB$1 [NC,L,NE,R=301]` and similarly build your rest of redirects on similar lines.

Comment: Hi @anubhava - Thanks again for your response. Unfortunately thats not the redirect I am looking for. Since I couldnt format the question corectly in a "comment", I have created a new post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249516/301-redirect-with-complex-directory-regex Can I please request you to take a look at it?

Comment: ok sure, always better to ask question in new posts rather than in comments, I will take a look.