# 301 redirect with complex directory regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using @anubhava's solution for folder redirect which works great. [301 redirect from one directory to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243074/301-redirect-from-one-directory-to-another/26243281?noredirect=1#comment41165465_26243281)

I realised that I also need to have a 301 redirect for the following

REDIRECT FROM

```
1) www.example.com/directory1/dirA/ 
2) www.example.com/directory1/dirB/
```

REDIRECT TO

```
1) www.example.com/directory2/new-path-dirA/ 
2) www.example.com/directory2/new-path-dirB/
```

EDIT: I have a lot of these redirects (about 40) and was wondering if there is way to have 1 Rewrite rule - instead of separate rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these new rules:

```
RewriteRule ^directory1/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /directory2/new-path-$1/$2 [NC,L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava! Sorry I should've been more clear in my question. I have a lot (about 40) of these and was wondering if there is a way to have 1 rule do the redirect - instead of separate rules.

Comment: Thanks again @anubhava. The site is live so I will try it again tonight and let you know. Truly appreciate all the help.

Comment: Sure let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62729/discussion-between-rogerb-and-anubhava).